# Why arr.filter(String) returns also numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing some little exercises to mantain fresh my knowledge of js quirks.  I tried to write some simple filters that returns me a new array containing certain elements wheater they are string, numbers, ecc ... and I was surprised of what arr.filter(String) produces when in the given array there are also Numbers.

```js
function onlyString(arr) {
  return arr.filter(String);
}
onlyString([2, 4, "", "omg", ]) // returns [2, 4, "omg"]
```

Then I wanted to see what arr.filter(Number) would retrun

```js
function onlyString(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Number);
}
onlyString([2, 4, "", "omg", ]) // returns [2, 4]
```

Also, I added an empty object inside arr to see what would happen:

```js
function onlyString(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Object);
}
onlyString([2, 4, "", "omg", {}]) // returns [2, 4, "", "omg", {}]
```

At first sight, here, I was more confused but then I thought that the return array is correct because in js everything is an object, or am I right in this case?

By the way, I really want to understand what happened under the hood in the String filter, hope you can help me

Comment: That's not how filter works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.filter` will filter out `arr` values depending on the result of `function` passed in it. If it's true, it will be stored in the array. If it's false, it will be removed from the array.

Now, if you check the result of `String()`, `Number()` & `Object()`, you will see that the values evaluating to false for example `"", 0, NaN` are filtered out. Others are returned in the array.

```js
function onlyString(arr) {
   return arr.filter(String);
}
console.log(String(2), String(4), String(""), String("omg"));
console.log(onlyString([2, 4, "", "omg", ]));


function onlyNumber(arr) {
   return arr.filter(Number);
}
console.log(Number(2), Number(4), Number(""), Number("omg"));
console.log(onlyNumber([2, 4, "", "omg", ]));


function onlyObject(arr) {
   return arr.filter(Object);
}
console.log(Object(2), Object(4), Object(""), Object("omg"));
console.log(onlyObject([2, 4, "", "omg", {}]));
```

Answer (score 10):

The functions you are passing to `.filter` are not "is this an instance of" predicates, they are the actual constructors for those types.

Therefore if that constructor accepts a given value and returns a newly created "truthy" object in response it will remain in the returned list, e.g.

- `String("")` -> `""` -> falsey -> filtered
- `Number("")` -> `0` -> falsey -> filtered
- `Number("omg")` -> `NaN` -> falsey -> filtered
- `Object("")` -> String("") -> truthy -> not-filtered

Here's another way to implement what you want using a generic helper function that creates a predicate function that matches the specified type.

```
function is(type) {
    return function(o) {
        return Object(o) instanceof type;
    }
}

function onlyString(array) { return array.filter(is(String)) };
```

usage:

```
onlyString([2, 4, "", "omg", ])
> [ "", "omg" ]
```

Comment: Notably, `Number("omg")` is `NaN`, which is falsy and therefore filtered out.

Comment: So, if I have understood, when I pass types construtors to a filter, what I should expect in return is basically a truthy or a falsey?

Comment: the elements for which the invoked function returns a "truthy" value are included.  The others are filtered out.   "Truthy" refers to whether the return value when implicitly treated as a boolean evaluates to `true` instead of `false`.   `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `NaN` are "falsey".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to filter only String type

```js
function onlyString(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function (el) {
        return typeof  el == 'string';
    });
 }
 console.log(onlyString([2, 4, "", "omg", ]));
```

Comment: Yes. The reason why I was trying the code I attached is because initially I passed to filter the Boolean constructor in order to get in return only true values. Then just for curiosity I wanted to see if replacing the Boolean constructor with another constructor I would produce a filtered array based on the given types