# Removing or Ignoring Empty Cells Returned by .getRange()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a column of data in a sheet, that I am iterating over with an apps script function.

The problem is that my sheet has a number of empty cells at the end, which are rendered as `[]` when I use `.getRange()`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AUD Data");
var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();

function logRange() {
Logger.log(sheetRange)
}
```

Returns
[image]

I want to get all these blank cells at the end, out of my cell array, as it is messing with results when I loop over this array.

Have tried [filter() and isNaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579300/how-to-ignore-empty-cell-values-for-getrange-getvalues) but those solutions didn't work.

Ideally I would like to remove the empty arrays, before looping, but a way of ignoring them in a condition would be fine too.

I find it interesting that even though these empty cells are displaying as empty arrays, Apps Script seems to treat them as having a value. My conditions should ignore imo... eg.

```
else if (i > 0 && sheetRange[i] <= 0 && sheetRange[i-1] <= 0)
```

How can an empty array be treated as a number?

**NOTE:** I can fix this by deleting the empty rows in the sheet, but would rather do this with code.

Comment: What are the value types? Are they numbers or strings or both?

Comment: Value types will just be numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure why filter didn't work to remove unwanted values. I don't have your data, but it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Issue 1:

In your spreadsheet, if the last row of all columns is the same or the last row of the column "F" is most bottom, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var sheetRange = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
```

Or if the last row of the column "F" is different from the last row of other columns, how about the following modified script?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AUD Data");
var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
for (var i = sheetRange.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (sheetRange[i][0]) {
    sheetRange.splice(i + 1, sheetRange.length - (i + 1));
    break;
  }
}
Logger.log(sheetRange)
```

Or if you want to also remove the empty elements of the middle of array, how about the following script?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AUD Data");
var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues().filter(String);
Logger.log(sheetRange)
```

### Issue 2:

About `else if (i > 0 && sheetRange[i] <= 0 && sheetRange[i-1] <= 0)`, from your script, I thought that you might use 2 dimensional array is used for this situation. If `sheetRange` is the value retrieved by `getValues()`, it is 2 dimensional array. And `getRange("F2:F")` is used for this. So how about this modification?

#### From:

```
else if (i > 0 && sheetRange[i] <= 0 && sheetRange[i-1] <= 0)
```

#### To:

```
else if (i > 0 && sheetRange[i][0] <= 0 && sheetRange[i-1][0] <= 0)
```

### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Tanaike. I should be the one apologizing... I didn't realize that .filter() needs to literally be .filter(String). I thought string was just a placeholder.

I will try the removal of the last row as well. Could be useful for similar functions where I do not want to remove the empty cells that are in the middle of the column.

Comment: @James H Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike so this `.filter(String)` is supposed to take a delegate. Is this basing resolving the String like a truthy statement? Basically `TypeOf(String) == true` then filter it out?

Comment: @Jay Jordan Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, are these threads useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49689907 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/36232576 If these were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, I meant to use the work "predicate" not "delegate". Yes, those links answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All of the cases in the filter should be eliminated with a simple truthy statement, but this will explicitly check to make sure none of those conditions happen.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("AUD Data");
var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();

sheetRange = sheetRange.filter(sheet => sheet != null && sheet != 'undefined' && sheet.trim() != '');

function logRange() {
     Logger.log(sheetRange)
}
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not valid apps script btw

Comment: Also, `getValues` returns an array of arrays (column array of row values), so a simple truthy test is incorrect.